# LINQ Help for a novice

Tags: .net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

not able to get this, can someone help for this LINQ query?

```
select col1, 
(select col2 from tbl2 where tbl2.ID=tbl1.tbl2ID) as [col2] 
from tbl1
```

scenario is like this

I want all records from Jobs table, Jobs has sectorID column, I also want SectorName. Also it has CountryID and CityID and I need CountryName and CityName too.

Comment: What does you data context look like? What does the data schema look like for the Jobs table and other table (Sector?)?

Comment: Structure is simple. Jobs table has few fields and SectorID (int), Sectors table has SectorName (nvarchar) and ID (int, primarykey) , Cities table has CityName (nvarchar) and ID (int, primarykey)  , Countries table has CountryName (nvarchar) and ID (int, primarykey)

Comment: I updated my answer based off of the three tables you explained.

Comment: thanks @davidisawesome but still @J Torres's answer suits my needs. Best luck next time. I appreciate everyone's effort here. Have a rocking time ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some joining.  Not knowing your structure, something like the following might work.

Create a simple view model to hold your information:

```
public class JobView
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    //Add any other fields you may need here
    public string SectorName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }

}
```

Then populate a list based on what you need

```
List<JobView> retVal = (from job in Jobs
                join sector in Sectors on job.SectorId equals sector.Id
                join country in Countries on job.CountryId equals country.Id
                join city in Cities on job.CityId equals city.Id
                select new JobView { 
                                JobId = job.Id,
                                JobName = job.JobName,
                                SectorName = sector.SectorName,
                                CountryName = country.CountryName,
                                CityName = city.CityName }).ToList();
    }
```

Any additional fields defined in JobView simply need to be populated during the select.

Comment: Structure is simple. Jobs table has few fields and SectorID (int), Sectors table has SectorName (nvarchar) and ID (int, primarykey) , Cities table has CityName (nvarchar) and ID (int, primarykey)  , Countries table has CountryName (nvarchar) and ID (int, primarykey)

Comment: Based on the plethora of answers you've received, you should be well on your way.  If you need a more elegant solution for an ORM, you may need to expand your question.  Based on your question, I would suggest using some form of ViewModel that has all of the columns you require and simply create an instance of that as proposed above.

Comment: I must tell this one was a perfect solution. It helped me overcome the error in the view
    `threw an exception of type Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' dynamic {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException`

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful to you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If the relationships are set up properly, I think it should be something like this:

```
var result=from job in Jobs
           select new {job.jobID, job.jobName, job.Sector.SectorName, job.Country.CountryName, job.City.CityName};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `JOIN` these tables like this:

```
from j in Jobs
join c in Countries on j.CountryID equals c.ID
join c2 in Cities on c.CityID equals c2.ID
select new 
{ 
    SectorName = j.SectorName,
    CountryName = c.Name,
    CityName = c2.Name
};
```

Comment: I also need columns from Jobs and the 3 columns you added.

Comment: @OjalSuthar, you can select what you whatever you want to select as I showed you, `j` is an alias for the `jobs` table use it to select the columns you want in the anonymous type `select new { j.Whatyouwanttoselect, j.anothercolumn,...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good sample I found that I think explains what you are looking for. Definitely need a JOIN.

```
class Job
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
}

class Sector
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string SectorName { get; set; }
}

class City
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string CityName { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
var jobs = new Job[]
{
    new Job{ID = 5, Name = "Sam", Title="Minion"},
    new Job{ID = 6, Name = "Dave", Title="Overlord"},
    new Job{ID = 7, Name = "Julia", Title="Minion"},
    new Job{ID = 8, Name = "Sue", Title="Minion"}
};

// Example orders.
var sectors = new Sector[]
{
    new Sector{ID = 5, SectorName = "Sector42"}
};

var cities = new City[]
{
    new City{ID = 5, CityName = "TownsVille"}
};

// Join on the ID properties.
var query = from j in jobs
        join s in sectors on j.ID equals s.ID
        join c in cities on j.ID equals c.ID
        select new { j.Name, j.Title, c.CityName, s.SectorName };

// Display joined groups.
foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Is a  {1} in {2}, sector {3}", group.Name, group.Title, group.CityName, group.SectorName);
}

}
```

The Output looks like this (from the foreach loop)

```
Sam Is a  Minion in TownsVille, sector Sector42
```

I referenced this site: http://www.dotnetperls.com/join